# Can't convert returned string from service to int in c#

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I create a service as you can see :

```
public int ValidateAndSubmitReception(NajaResult ReceptionData)
{
    ClientRequest.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
    serializerToUplaod = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(NajaResult));
    serializerToUplaod.WriteObject(ms, ReceptionData);
    string Result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ClientRequest.UploadData(ServiceHostName + "/ReceptionService.svc/ValidateAndSubmitReception", "POST", ms.ToArray()));
    return int.Parse(Result.ToString());
    //return receptionid

}
```

My service returns `"\"-1\""` but when i click on magnifier it shows me -1,
so when i want to convert to int it throw a convert exception .why ?

[image]

Here my service interface

```
   [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/ValidateAndSubmitReception", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

        string ValidateAndSubmitReception(NajaResult NajaResult);
```

Comment: Because the exact string is not `-1`, it is `"-1"`. Remove the quotation marks with `Result.Replace("\"", string.Empty)` and try again.

Comment: You need to remove your quotation mark. it's `"-1"`, not `-1`

Comment: Your string contains quotes

Comment: try "Convert.ToInt32(Result.ToString())"

Comment: This is what you should do: `Result = Result.Replace("\"", string.Empty)` then `return int.Parse(Result)` (removing quotes before `int.Parse`)

Comment: Thank you all guys very much .But i want to know why these quotation marks are created ?

Comment: They are created because your response is probably a JSON object. JSON objects have quotation marks around them, that gives them their structure.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar: Well we have no idea how the service you're connecting to is specified.

Comment: @IanH.: It would still have been a valid JSON value to just be -1 without the quotes. Quotes make it a JSON *string* value, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, ignore the backslashes in the debugger. They're misleading. The string you've got is:

```
"-1"
```

That's the *actual text* of the string, as you'd see it if you printed it to the console.

While you *could* just remove the quotes manually, I would personally take a different tack: it looks like the service is returning JSON, so use a JSON parser to parse the token... and to perform the subsequent `int` conversion:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string response = "\"-1\"";
        JToken token = JToken.Parse(response);
        int value = (int) token;
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

That way if the service ever returns a value which is perfectly valid JSON, but *isn't* just a decimal number wrapped in quotes, your code will still cope. For example, support the service decides (validly, but unusually) to escape the '-' character, like this:

```
"\u002d1"
```

This code will be fine with that - it will unescape the string *because it's treating it as JSON*.

Comment: Thank you for your awesome answer .

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** Your string contains quotation mark (`"`) in it so it wouldn't be parsed the way your are trying to parse it.

**Solution:** You should remove the quotation mark (`"`) first using the [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) method and then try to parse the string.

**Code:** You may need to replace the `int.parse` statement with the following:

```
return int.Parse(Result.Replace("\"", string.Empty));
```

Comment: I would say it's actually "Problem: the service is returning JSON, but you're treating it as plain text." The solution to that is to treat the response as JSON instead...

Comment: I am calling it a problem just because it is the possible reason behind the issue.

Comment: My point is that you're looking at the initial symptom rather than the underlying reason. If the service accepts and returns JSON, treat it as JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I am not much familiar with `JSON` so I suggested the solution in context with `C#` conversion :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Result` string returns the integer inside of quotation marks. Remove them, and try to parse it again.

```
string Result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ClientRequest.UploadData(ServiceHostName + "/ReceptionService.svc/ValidateAndSubmitReception", "POST", ms.ToArray()));
Result = Result.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
return int.Parse(Result);
```